# iphone - TabBarController rotation question

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, rotation

My app has 4 tabs. All the view controllers support rotation, and indeed are rotated when I rotate the device. For one of the view controllers, I need to reposition some of the subviews upon rotation. I do this in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation of that view controller, and it works fine.

The problem comes when I switch to a different tab, then rotate the device, then go back to the original tab. It apparently has not received the rotation notification, since willRotateToInterfaceOrientation has not been called. So it seems as though only the "active" view controller gets notified that the device has rotated.

The question: how do you get all the view controllers (controlled by a TabBarController) to rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug in iOS 3.x. It works fine in iOS 4.x. I've seen apps that manually keep track of orientation changes and then do the rotation manually for inactive viewcontrollers. Sucks.

Comment: Hmm. This is an iPad app, so I'm testing on iPad simulator 3.2. You're saying that once I can build with iPad 4.0 it will magically start working?

Comment: It will presumably work for iPads on 4.0+; users who haven't upgraded will of course still get the bug.

Comment: I am facing the same issue on 4.3.5.  I'm not sure that it is an iOS 3.x bug.  The views that rotate correctly with autoresizing masks work fine when going from tab to tab, but if custom rotation code is required, I have found that none of the rotation methods are called automatically and you have two options, monitor rotation changes through NSNotifications, or perform the hack on viewWillAppear.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the iOS 3.2 docs to make sure this works, there is a `viewControllers` property in `UITabBarController`. Try something like this:

```
for (UIViewController * viewController in tabBarController) {
    // Do stuff here with each 'viewController'.
}
```

I recommend that you do something with the `UIViewController`'s `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method but you may have another way in which you plan on achieving the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check for the interface orientation in viewWillAppear method of the controller whose subviews frame you are changing.Because when you move to the new tab and rotate the device and now when you tap another tab the viewWillAppear method will we called and there you can change the frames accordingly.
I also faced the same problem which i sorted out using this approach